# A script to rewrite all images that are a certain width in a different size?

Tags: php, gd

I am using the GD library with PHP.

Basically, I've made a design change and need to resize a whole bunch of images that are a certain width.

ie anything that is 876px wide needs to be 828px.

Is there a way to loop through all JPG files in a directory, check their width dimension, and if they equal X then grab their existing file name, rescale down to the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to use [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) in a loop.

```
$path = "/my/path/to/jpgs";
$targetWidth = 876;
$newWidth = 828;
$imageQuality = 95;

if (is_dir($path)) {
    $dHandle = opendir($path);
    if ($dHandle) {
        while (($cFileName = readdir($dHandle)) !== false) {
            if (!preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $cFileName)) {
                continue;
            }

            $cImagePath = $path . $cFileName;
            list ($cWidth, $cHeight) = getimagesize($cImagePath);

            if ($cWidth == $targetWidth) {
                $cImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($cImagePath);
                if ($cImage === false) {
                    echo "Error reading: " . $cImagePath . "\n";
                    continue;
                }

                $cNewHeight = round($cHeight * ($newWidth / $cWidth));

                $cNewImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $cNewHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($cNewImage, $cImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $cNewHeight, $cWidth, $cHeight);

                if (imagejpeg($cNewImage, $cImagePath, $imageQuality) === false) {
                    echo "Error writing: " . $cImagePath . "\n";
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($dHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've fiddled it with for a while and can't seem to get past if($dHandle). So, it is_dir on my $path.. so that path is true, but can't opendir. I thought it was permission based - so I played around, and eventually even set it to chmod 777 with no luck. Any ideas on this one? The code looks great otherwise and looks like it should work.

Comment: @KeenLearner: Rather annoyingly, I had a typo - I wrote `opendir($dir)` rather than `opendir($path)` - had you copied that verbatim?  That's what happens when you write code in a browser untested! ;-)

Comment: Aha! When I copied the code originally there was a missing brackets also which led me to believe you wrote this code without testing it. I was mostly impressed you have a great understanding of the code!

Comment: Thanks for this. It works and does the job. I think I'm losing a bit of image quality though in the downsizing. Is that typical for imagecopyresampled?

Comment: @KeenLearner: I fixed the bracket now, thanks for letting me know.  `imagecopyresampled()` is a better (higher quality) routine than `imagecopyresized()` which is often used for speed.  JPEG is a lossy format, you usually lose some quality on saving.  However, there is a quality argument (0-100) for [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), make it higher and the image will be better quality.  Try 95 to start, and decrease to an acceptable level, I will modify the code to suit. Note that higher quality = bigger files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Much better quality!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of image resize scripts out there...just google... but if you're looking to build something yourself, you would basically use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)